# Datatable js searchPanes show/hide column's filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I work with library datatable, and use **filtering pane** and with this i have issues.

So problem is, i want to chosse which column i will filter, for now script is auto create filtering from **column 2,3,4**, but i want to have filtering **from column 0,1,3,4**.

How i can solve it?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#stationTypesList').DataTable({
        searchPanes: {
            layout: 'columns-4',
        },
        dom: 'Pfrtip',
    });
});
```

[Library link](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: I don't use it, but 1 min look at your link and: https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchPanes.columns `searchPanes:{
            columns:[1,3,5]
        },` If not, read documentation  in more detail

Comment: @ikiK but i want not 3 filters, but 4, how i can add one more

Comment: well did you try  `columns:[0,1,3,4]` ?!?

Comment: @ikiK yes, this is not working

Comment: @ikiK it;s working only for column 2,3,4 it's dont want to appear 0,1 and 5 column

Comment: Sorry I can only guess without seeing working example. Make a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/initialisation/forceShow.html) about hide/show search panes.

**And here is a working example:**

```
$('#stationTypesList').DataTable({
        searchPanes: true,
        dom: 'Pfrtip',
        columnDefs:[
            {
                searchPanes:{
                    show: false, // It can be true/false
                },
                targets: [0,1,2,3,4,5], // Index of columns (starting at 0) that you want show/hide
            }
        ]
    });
```

**Result:**

[image]

**All HTML code for test:**

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.1.1/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js" ></script>
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.1.1/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


</head>




<body>
    <table id="stationTypesList">
        <thead>
            <th>Test 1</th>
            <th>Test 2</th>
            <th>Test 3</th>
            <th>Test 4</th>
            <th>Test 5</th>
            <th>Test 6</th>
            <th>Test 7</th>
            <th>Test 8</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a2</td>
                <td>b2</td>
                <td>c2</td>
                <td>d2</td>
                <td>e2</td>
                <td>f2</td>
                <td>g2</td>
                <td>h2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a3</td>
                <td>b3</td>
                <td>c3</td>
                <td>d3</td>
                <td>e3</td>
                <td>f3</td>
                <td>g3</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a4</td>
                <td>b4</td>
                <td>c4</td>
                <td>d4</td>
                <td>e4</td>
                <td>f4</td>
                <td>g4</td>
                <td>h4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a5</td>
                <td>b5</td>
                <td>c5</td>
                <td>d5</td>
                <td>e5</td>
                <td>f5</td>
                <td>g5</td>
                <td>h5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a6</td>
                <td>b6</td>
                <td>c6</td>
                <td>d6</td>
                <td>e6</td>
                <td>f6</td>
                <td>g6</td>
                <td>h6</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a2</td>
                <td>b2</td>
                <td>c2</td>
                <td>d2</td>
                <td>e2</td>
                <td>f2</td>
                <td>g2</td>
                <td>h2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a3</td>
                <td>b3</td>
                <td>c3</td>
                <td>d3</td>
                <td>e3</td>
                <td>f3</td>
                <td>g3</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a4</td>
                <td>b4</td>
                <td>c4</td>
                <td>d4</td>
                <td>e4</td>
                <td>f4</td>
                <td>g4</td>
                <td>h4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a5</td>
                <td>b5</td>
                <td>c5</td>
                <td>d5</td>
                <td>e5</td>
                <td>f5</td>
                <td>g5</td>
                <td>h5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a6</td>
                <td>b6</td>
                <td>c6</td>
                <td>d6</td>
                <td>e6</td>
                <td>f6</td>
                <td>g6</td>
                <td>h6</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a2</td>
                <td>b2</td>
                <td>c2</td>
                <td>d2</td>
                <td>e2</td>
                <td>f2</td>
                <td>g2</td>
                <td>h2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a3</td>
                <td>b3</td>
                <td>c3</td>
                <td>d3</td>
                <td>e3</td>
                <td>f3</td>
                <td>g3</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a4</td>
                <td>b4</td>
                <td>c4</td>
                <td>d4</td>
                <td>e4</td>
                <td>f4</td>
                <td>g4</td>
                <td>h4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a5</td>
                <td>b5</td>
                <td>c5</td>
                <td>d5</td>
                <td>e5</td>
                <td>f5</td>
                <td>g5</td>
                <td>h5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a6</td>
                <td>b6</td>
                <td>c6</td>
                <td>d6</td>
                <td>e6</td>
                <td>f6</td>
                <td>g6</td>
                <td>h6</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a2</td>
                <td>b2</td>
                <td>c2</td>
                <td>d2</td>
                <td>e2</td>
                <td>f2</td>
                <td>g2</td>
                <td>h2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a3</td>
                <td>b3</td>
                <td>c3</td>
                <td>d3</td>
                <td>e3</td>
                <td>f3</td>
                <td>g3</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a4</td>
                <td>b4</td>
                <td>c4</td>
                <td>d4</td>
                <td>e4</td>
                <td>f4</td>
                <td>g4</td>
                <td>h4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a5</td>
                <td>b5</td>
                <td>c5</td>
                <td>d5</td>
                <td>e5</td>
                <td>f5</td>
                <td>g5</td>
                <td>h5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a6</td>
                <td>b6</td>
                <td>c6</td>
                <td>d6</td>
                <td>e6</td>
                <td>f6</td>
                <td>g6</td>
                <td>h6</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a2</td>
                <td>b2</td>
                <td>c2</td>
                <td>d2</td>
                <td>e2</td>
                <td>f2</td>
                <td>g2</td>
                <td>h2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a3</td>
                <td>b3</td>
                <td>c3</td>
                <td>d3</td>
                <td>e3</td>
                <td>f3</td>
                <td>g3</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a4</td>
                <td>b4</td>
                <td>c4</td>
                <td>d4</td>
                <td>e4</td>
                <td>f4</td>
                <td>g4</td>
                <td>h4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a5</td>
                <td>b5</td>
                <td>c5</td>
                <td>d5</td>
                <td>e5</td>
                <td>f5</td>
                <td>g5</td>
                <td>h5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a6</td>
                <td>b6</td>
                <td>c6</td>
                <td>d6</td>
                <td>e6</td>
                <td>f6</td>
                <td>g6</td>
                <td>h6</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
                <td>g</td>
                <td>h</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a2</td>
                <td>b2</td>
                <td>c2</td>
                <td>d2</td>
                <td>e2</td>
                <td>f2</td>
                <td>g2</td>
                <td>h2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a3</td>
                <td>b3</td>
                <td>c3</td>
                <td>d3</td>
                <td>e3</td>
                <td>f3</td>
                <td>g3</td>
                <td>h3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a4</td>
                <td>b4</td>
                <td>c4</td>
                <td>d4</td>
                <td>e4</td>
                <td>f4</td>
                <td>g4</td>
                <td>h4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a5</td>
                <td>b5</td>
                <td>c5</td>
                <td>d5</td>
                <td>e5</td>
                <td>f5</td>
                <td>g5</td>
                <td>h5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>a6</td>
                <td>b6</td>
                <td>c6</td>
                <td>d6</td>
                <td>e6</td>
                <td>f6</td>
                <td>g6</td>
                <td>h6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$('#stationTypesList').DataTable({
        searchPanes: true,
        dom: 'Pfrtip',
        columnDefs:[
            {
                searchPanes:{
                    show: false,
                },
                targets: [0,1,2,3,4,5],
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```